# hdfs jmxget vs hdfs fsck

Tags: hadoop, hdfs

I have 2 namenodes with several datanodes, but today I've just seen that I have some corrupt blocks.

What is awkward is that:

```
hdfs jmxget -server namenode02 -port 8006 | grep  CorruptBlocks

CorruptBlocks=27
```

and when I've checked with `hdfs fsck /` , I've got:

```
Total size:    734930879995888 B (Total open files size: 537967073 B)
 Total dirs:    1501316
 Total files:   113743394
 Total symlinks:                0 (Files currently being written: 137)
 Total blocks (validated):      109063040 (avg. block size 6738587 B) (Total open file blocks (not validated): 133)
 Minimally replicated blocks:   109063040 (100.00001 %)
 Over-replicated blocks:        0 (0.0 %)
 Under-replicated blocks:       0 (0.0 %)
 Mis-replicated blocks:         0 (0.0 %)
 Default replication factor:    3
 Average block replication:     3.001944
 Corrupt blocks:                0
 Missing replicas:              0 (0.0 %)
 Number of data-nodes:          103
 Number of racks:               1
FSCK ended at Mon Feb 12 10:09:10 CET 2018 in 1608344 milliseconds
```

So with fsck nothing bad regarding the blocks. How is this check made?

Thx in advance!

Answer (score 0):

For the hdfs jmx command we have the overall status of the blocks from Hadoop, which it seems that few of them might be corrupted (don't know the reason).
For the fsck command we have the status of the files which they are safe due to the replica number set.
To conclude it's normal behavior, no anomalies here.